# Python script syntax error even after changes

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project thats been working 100% as expected, until today when it gave a syntax error.

I've done the following:

- The line its giving an error for has been changed several times, but the error doesnt change
- I've uninstalled and reinstalled Jinja2 3 times
- I've deleted the pycache folders several times
- I've removed all mention of jinja2 in the pipelines.py file
- I've converted the "tabs to spaces" and trimmed whitespace (using VSCode)

Whats going on????

My Pipelines.py file

```
# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html


# useful for handling different item types with a single interface
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from gumtree.models import Result, db_connect, create_table
from scrapy.mail import MailSender
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from jinja2 import Template


class GumtreePipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item


class DuplicatesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates tables.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.Session()
        instance = session.query(Result).filter_by(**item).one_or_none()
        session.close()

        if instance:  # the current result exists
            raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
        else:
            return item


class SaveResultsPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker
        Creates tables
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save results in the database
        This method is called for every item pipeline component
        """
        session = self.Session()
        result = Result()
        result.title = item["title"]

        # # check whether the result exists
        instance = session.query(Result).filter_by(**item).one_or_none()
        if instance:
            return instance
        gt_item = Result(**item)

        try:
            session.add(gt_item)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        return item


class SendEmailPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items_cache = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.items_cache.append(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        items = self.items_cache
        self.send_mail(items)

    def send_mail(self, items):

        # env = Environment(
        #     loader=PackageLoader("gumtree"),
        #     autoescape=select_autoescape()
        # )
        # template = env.get_template("results.html")

        template = Template(
        """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Latest Gumtree Results</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                html {width: 100%};
                body {background-color: lightgray;};
                #content {text-align: center;};
                .important { color: #336699; };
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content">
                {% for item in items -%}
                    <a href="{{item.ad_link}}">{{item.title}} - {{item.price}}</a><br><br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                &copy; Copyright 2021 <a href="http://domain.invalid/">Early Bird Dealers</a>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        """
        )
```

**EDIT**
error

```
(py39) c:\laragon\www\GT>scrapy crawl gumtree
2021-07-23 14:02:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.0 started (bot: gumtree)
2021-07-23 14:02:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.9.5 (default, May 18 2021, 14:42:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021), cryptography 3.4.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
2021-07-23 14:02:30 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-07-23 14:02:30 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'gumtree',
 'MAIL_FROM': '...',
 'MAIL_HOST': 'email-smtp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
 'MAIL_PASS': '...',
 'MAIL_PORT': 587,
 'MAIL_USER': '...',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'gumtree.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['gumtree.spiders']}
2021-07-23 14:02:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: ...
2021-07-23 14:02:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-07-23 14:02:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy_crawl_once.CrawlOnceMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-07-23 14:02:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_crawl_once.CrawlOnceMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2021-07-23 14:02:30 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1656, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1571, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1445, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(g.send, result)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 61, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 851, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 988, in get_code

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 918, in source_to_code

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

builtins.SyntaxError: invalid syntax (pipelines.py, line 93)

2021-07-23 14:02:30 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1445, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(g.send, result)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 61, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\users\stefa\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 851, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 988, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 918, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\laragon\www\GT\gumtree\pipelines.py", line 93
    from jinja2
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Haha sorry guys, fried brain

Comment: Where and how did you uninstall and install Jinja2?

Comment: using Conda virtual env: pip uninstall jinja2; pip install jinja2

Comment: The `jinja2` module is installed with `pip install Jinja2` (note capitalization).

Comment: noted, reinstalled using "Jinja2" but error remains

Comment: The traceback shows a line consisting solely of `from jinja2` (which is indeed a syntax error) at line 93.  There's nothing like that in the code you posted, so I have to conclude that you aren't showing us the contents of the relevant file - `c:\laragon\www\GT\gumtree\pipelines.py`

Comment: if you copy paste the code you show here back into your files and run _that_, does the error persist? Also, does any part of your code come from something you copy/pasted from a website? (i.e. might there be invisible characters like a &nbsp; etc that are causing the syntax error?)

Comment: you show code with `from jinja2 import Template` but error show `from jinja2` in file `c:\laragon\www\GT\gumtree\pipelines.py` in line `93` - so maybe you runs different code then you show in question. And you should open `c:\laragon\www\GT\gumtree\pipelines.py` and check what you have in line `93`